# data is not coming through in php form

Tags: php

this is the code please help me I am connected to the database

so i use mysqli_real_escape_string to get the clear data and save it into my table but it give me a nothing in my data

```
<?php 
$db_connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "master_wn");
if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
    session_start();
    $name   = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $name2  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['name2']);
    $email  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $case   = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['case']);
    $phone  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
    $adress = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['adress']);
    $sex    = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['sex']);
    $prove  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['prove']);
    $quali  = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['quali']);
    $exper  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['exper']);


    $query = "INSERT INTO `stu_data` (`number`,`name`,`name2`,`email`,`phone`,`address`,`sex`,`cases`,`prove`,`quali`,`exper`) VALUES ('','$name','$name2','$email','$phone','$adress','$sex','$case','$prove','$quali','$exper')";
$q = mysqli_query($db_connect,$query);
if ($q){

        header("location:step2.php"); 
    }
    else 
    {
        "try again";
    }
}
 ?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            test
        </title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/normliaze.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <div class="global">
       <!--Star Header-->
        <div class="header">

            <div class="boy">
                <h1>خطوات التقديم لحجز مقعد للدراسات العليا</h1>
                <img src="../images/logo.PNG" alt="logo" width="90" height="80">

                <p>موقع التقديم للدراسات العليا</p>


            </div>
        </div>
       <!--End Header-->
        <div class="holdForm">
<div class="container">

    <form class="well form-horizontal" action="step1.php" method="post"  id="contact_form">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>الخطوة الاولي </legend>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input   placeholder="Name" class="form-control"  type="text" name = "name">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >الاسم</label> 
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input  placeholder="الاسم بالعربي" class="form-control"  type="text"  name="name2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
       <div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
  <input  placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control"  type="text"  name="email">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- radio checks -->
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">الحالة الاجتماعية</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="case" value="marig" /> متزوج
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="case" value="single" /> اعزب
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="case" value="widow" /> ارمل
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">الهاتف</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
  <input  placeholder="(+249)555-1212" class="form-control" type="text"  name="phone">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">السكن</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
  <input  placeholder="Address" class="form-control" type="text"  name="adress">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




 <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">الجنس</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="mail" /> ذكر
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="radio">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="fmail" /> اثتي
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

<!-- Text area -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">اثبات شخصية</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i></span>
  <input  placeholder="Address" class="form-control" type="text"  name="prove">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group"> 
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">المؤهل العلمي</label>
    <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
    <select  class="form-control selectpicker"  name="quali">
      <option value=" " >... اختر مؤهل</option>
      <option  name="select1">دبلوم عالي</option>
      <option  name="select2">بكلاريوس</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">سنوات الخبرة</label>  
    <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
  <input name="exper" placeholder="Address" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Success message -->
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message">Success <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly.</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-send" name="send" value="التالي" > 
  </div>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
        </div>
<div id="footer">
<p class="p2">جميع الحقوق محفوظة للمبرمج محمد تاج الدين &copy; 2017-2018</p>
</div><!--end footer-->
</div><!--end all-->
       <!--End content-->
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/plugin.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is the code please help me I am connected to the database

so i use mysqli_real_escape_string to get the clear data and save it into my table but it give me a nothing in my data this is the code please help me I am connected to the database

so i use mysqli_real_escape_string to get the clear data and save it into my table but it give me a nothing in my data

Comment: the error is clear to me yet you failed to read the manual on `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and you're also mixing with `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Comment: One of these mysqli_real_escape_strings is not like the others.  One of these mysqli_real_escape_strings just doesn't belong.

Comment: `"try again";` didn't help you and it doesn't even do anything; a parse error if anything.